# Office Add-In MSAL SSO Fails in 'Office for the Web' MacOS

Tags: angular, macos, single-sign-on, office-addins, msal

I have Office Add-In MSAL working correctly on the PC (Excel Desktop App and Excel Office on Web) and on MacOS Excel Desktop App. However, it consistently fails on MacOS for Excel Office on the Web (MacOS Big Sur, 11.7.9 with Safari 16.6, Angular 16.1.5 and MSAL-angular 3.0.0)

Safari console shows two errors:

```
1. Blocked a frame with origin "https://onedrive.live.com" from accessing a frame with origin 
"https://excelofficeapps.live.com". Protocol, domains and ports must match
```

and

```
2. getAccessToken() Exception Thrown.  API Not supported in this platform
```

I mention the first error because it always seems to occur just before the call to getAccessToken(), and thus may be related. But all other Officee.js functions work.

Does anyone have any ideas on either of these errors?